# How does the PyCharm autocomplete tool handle namedtuple instances?

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm

I'm currently learning how to create objects dynamically in python and ran into a problem.
The autocomplete tool in PyCharm generally doesn't show hints for dynamically created objects. However, autocomplete works for `NamedTuple` class and its instances when created dynamically. I looked at the source code for `namedtuple` function in `collections` module and found out that it creates the needed object with `type` built-in passing there the type name and a namespace as a `dict`.

```py
def namedtuple(typename, field_names, *, rename=False, defaults=None, module=None):

    _tuplegetter = lambda index, doc: property(_itemgetter(index), doc=doc)

    # many lines of code
    
    class_namespace = {
        '__doc__': f'{typename}({arg_list})',
        '__slots__': (),
        '_fields': field_names,
        # and so on
    }
    for index, name in enumerate(field_names):
        doc = _sys.intern(f'Alias for field number {index}')
        class_namespace[name] = _tuplegetter(index, doc)

    result = type(typename, (tuple,), class_namespace)

    return result
```

So, I created two classes, the first one with `namedtuple` factory and the other with `type` built-in.

```py
from collections import namedtuple

Movie = namedtuple('Movie', ['title', 'year'])
SomeObject = type('SomeObject', (object,), {'text': 'some text'})
```

When creating a class using `namedtuple` factory, I can see its fields in autocompletion hints

Autocompltetion with `namedtuple`:
[image: autocomplete with namedtuple]

However, when creating my custom class with `type` I could not get the hints to its dynamically created attributes

Autocompletion with `SomeObject`:
[image: autocompletion with SomeObject]

I wonder if there is some additional static code analysis happens in the case of `namedtuple` function? And if so, how does this happen? Is there a possibility to make autocomplete work for my custom dynamically created objects?

Comment: I don't believe `type` creates a class.

Comment: @Shiv It [does](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) when three arguments are given.

Comment: @Shiv it does create a class, it is a metaclass. Classes are just instances of `type`, e.g. `class Foo: pass` then `isinstance(Foo, type)` will be true

Comment: I suspect it is special cased, but I don't think any of this is open sourced so we can only speculate

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, it seems like that. Maybe, I should ask that question to PyCharm developers in its community.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't expect dynamically created things to be amenable to static analysis.